# How can I merge multiple arrays into multiple separate objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have an object that has multiple arrays that looks something like this.

```
let obj = { 
    links: ["https://somelink.com/image.jpg", "https://somelink.com/image2.jpg"],
    IDs: ["yCmj", "4q1K"],
}
```

I want to make it so that it's turned into an array of objects. Like the following.

```
let newObj = {
   templates: [
      {id:"yCmj", link: "https://somelink.com/image.jpg"}, 
      {id:"4q1K", link: "https://somelink.com/image2.jpg"}
   ] 
}
```

**What I have tried:**

I tried mapping the object values to a new array but the second map overwrites the whole array.

```
let templates = obj.templateIDs.map((id) => ({id}))
templates = obj.thumbnailLinks.map((thumbnailLink) => ({thumbnailLink}))

let newObj = templates
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish this would be to pick either `obj.links` or `obj.IDs` and map their values to an object and use the `index` to locate the corresponding parallel value.

```js
const obj = {
  links: ["https://somelink.com/image.jpg", "https://somelink.com/image2.jpg"],
  IDs: ["yCmj", "4q1K"],
};

const newObj = {
  templates: obj.links.map((link, index) => (id => ({ id, link }))(obj.IDs[index]))
};

console.log(newObj);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: I completely forgot that `map` accepts callbacks and also has the `index` parameter... that's much better.

Answer (score 1):

This operation is typically called "zipping" 2 arrays:

```js
const zip = (a,b, zipper) => {
  if(a.length != b.length)
    throw "arrays must be the same length";
    
  return a.map( (v,i) => zipper(v,b[i]))
}

const obj = { 
    links: ["https://somelink.com/image.jpg", "https://somelink.com/image2.jpg"],
    IDs: ["yCmj", "4q1K"],
}

const newObj = {
  templates: zip(obj.links, obj.IDs, (link,id) => ({link,id}))
}

console.log(newObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `map`.

```js
const obj = {
  links: ["https://somelink.com/image.jpg", "https://somelink.com/image2.jpg"],
  IDs: ["yCmj", "4q1K"],
};

const newObj = {
  templates: obj.links.map((link, i) => ({ link, id: obj.IDs[i] })),
};

console.log(newObj);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let obj = { 
    links: ["https://somelink.com/image.jpg", "https://somelink.com/image2.jpg","https://somelink.com/image2.jpg"],
    IDs: ["yCmj", "4q1K","34er"],
}
let propsKey = Object.keys(obj)
let finalArr =  obj.links.map( ()=> {
         return {}
})

propsKey.forEach( (prop) => {
  obj[prop].forEach( (v,i)=>finalArr[i][prop] = v  )
})
 

console.log(finalArr)
```